# VBA paste from Excel to Word ends sub

Tags: excel, ms-word, office-2013, vba

The overall aim is to take RTF formatted text in Excel and convert it to HTML. I have been unable thus far to get Excel to respond in a sensible way so tried using Word. I am able to convert in Word without issue so want to automate the process by copying the cell out Excel, pasting into Word and then running code to convert the formatting into the way I want.

I am running into an issue where when I paste into Word from Excel VBA, the paste is successful but then it jumps to `End Sub`.

```vb
Sub webtext(r As String)
    Range(r).Copy
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    wordApp.Visible = True
    wordApp.Activate

    wordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial

    'Any code here is missed out
    z = MsgBox("tada") 'this will never trigger
    x=5 'this will never set
    With wordDoc
        'Operations on the text pasted would happen here
        'but vba never gets here.
    End With

'Code jumps to here
End Sub
```

I have tried using both wordDoc and wordApp, and both paste and pastespecial but it always has the same result.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on here or how to stop it from always ending after the paste.

EDIT: I have tested this and it worked on Office 2010. It does not work on Office 2013.

Comment: You run the `webtext` in Excel, correct? When the code *jumps* to `End Sub` is your task achieved or not? I have to admit I have hard time understanding your question here

Comment: I have added a couple of "test" points to illustrate where the issue is happening and the fallout from it (ie: I can't run any more code after the paste). The paste itself is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be solved. VBA debugger cannot understand what is going on after it hits the WordApp section and so the code *appears* to jump to the end of the section.

Additionally, it seems that any word alterations should be done within the `With wordDoc` section as it can be a little odd at hitting code properly in between sometimes (though never figured out why was missing message box first time round).

Thanks @brettdj for help with testing and apologies for my error in understanding what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

It worked fine for me as is

But suggest you try these tweaks to see if this works (`AppActivate` is redundant).

```
Sub StartIt()
Call webtext("a1:a10")
End Sub
```

**main**

```
Sub webtext(r As String)
    Range(r).Copy
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    wordApp.Visible = True

    With wordDoc
    .ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: My calling function is identical:

    `Sub wt()
        Call webtext("B4")
    End Sub`

I added the ActiveWindow code and it still jumped to End Sub. I also tried adding it to the `With wordDoc` section and jumps straight out of it after successfully pasting.

Comment: Are you using Office 2013? I just tried this on 2010 and it worked leading me to assume that it might be a 2013 thing.

Comment: Interestingly just tried this again in a new sheet and its working for me now too.